# How to execute .ds2 or binary files generated from SAS enterprise miner models through oozie?

Tags: hadoop, sas, scheduling, oozie, sas-ds2

I have some scoring models created in SAS e miner .
I need to schedule the .ds2 or binary files generated from eminer through oozie.
Is it possible ??
The scoring model Jobs are written in SAS data step.
So if the jobs run on SAS environment , not on hadoop , it's fine.

But I just want to use oozie for scheduling these jobs .

Comment: As long as you do not use extension nodes enterprise miner can output java or pmml codes. These should be no problem for oozie. The only solution I see when sticking to the SAS datastep includes is to schedule a SAS program utilizing a datastep and the score codes.

Comment: I am new to SAS , So I am confused with the below idea. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/gridref/67944/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0ym34a0eu6yb7n1bf1buxb85nk7.htm                               It says SAS data step jobs written in DI studio can be scheduled via oozie , But if there are already exported models from eminer will it be possible. And how exactly the .ds2 or binary files are different from DI studio jobs.

Comment: Are you running the scoring accelerator? take a look at this paper: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings14/SAS033-2014.pdf

Comment: Yes , The modeling team uses Scoring accelerator for deploying it . But not sure if they deploy to hdfs. So if the SAS code is deployed to HDFS , can it be scheduled using oozie webHDFS ?  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/scheduleug/68697/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p11aer7ye54mt6n105rh046nu75h.htm

Comment: Well the SAS way would be to access oozie through the sas scheduler, but if you have prepared your sas program you should just be able to exec it on the sas batch server via webHDFS.